# How can I filter messages according to content in Weavy?

Tags: filter, weavy

Filtering messages according to contents is really useful during searching for a particular message from the bunch. From the initial integration in a simple react application, I couldn't find any feature to filter messages based on their contents. Is there any feature in Weavy so that I can filter messages according to content?

I tried to find docs related to filtering messages from the official Weavy docs but didn't find any related materials. Hence, want to ask if this feature is present and, if yes, how to enable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Weavy Web API you can search for messages with certain text by supplying the `q` query string parameter. For instance `/api/apps/{id}/messages?q=test` will find all messages containing the text 'test'.